# Covalent 3.0 Platform Requirements

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

Covalent ERS 3.0 should work on windows platform other than 2003 version.

What is difference between Covalent ERS 3.0 and Covalent ERS 2.0?

What are required platform requirements for both?

Please reply to this question...

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: ya i did but it is mentioned only windows platform, not sure about windows server versions. do u have any idea about it?? or can u share the link for version 2.0 and 3.0?